# Move a javascript element into the right position on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html

The webpage in question is [here](http://makemoneyonlinetonight.com/).

I am trying to make the signup form, which you can obviously see is out of place, sit right in between "Sign up now & grab your copy!" and "We will not sell, rent..."

What modification to the code should I do? I tried using a  tag to center it but that didn't work.

[The page source is here.](http://pastebin.com/hhbYcbnb)

Comment: I think you mean HTML element not javascript element. This is more suited by a change in CSS styling not javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your css:

```
.wf-formTpl {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

The problem is the script tag is actually writing new DOM elements to the page, so you don't want to put the margin on the container or script tag, but rather the new elements that are being added. It looks like whatever service you are using put's a class of .wf-formTpl to the new element.

**Edit:** As suggested by Scott Michael in the comments. If you only have the HTML file, just wrap the style in `<style>` tags and put it in the HEAD of the document:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .wf-formTpl {
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 200px;
  }
</style>
```

Not ideal, but there are inline styles all over that page anyway.

Comment: This is a pre-made template I am inserting my own form into. There is no CSS, just the html file.

Comment: This looks like a good solution for what OP needs. Also OP has crappy choice in template selection as the markup is HORRENDOUS. Add style tags around what jhummel sent you and put it at the top of the html page. This is not the best solution, but that markup is ugly anyway so it probably doesnt matter too much.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. @ScottMitchell When the template is free, you get what you get I guess...